# Sort NSMutableArray with numbers greater than 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsmutablearray

My app has a high score list that contains all the scores a player has made. I use an `NSMutableArray` for this, which I sort and show in descending order in a `UITableView`.

```
[arrayWithScores sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
reversed = [[arrayWithScores reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
```

This works, however when a player achieves a score greater than 10, the array is no longer sorted the way I want it to.

For example, what it does:

```
7, 5, 4, ... 10,
```

It puts the 10 at the end because it starts with 1, which obviously is the lowest score in this array. But I want it to handle it as 10 instead and put it at the beginning.

What I want in this case:

```
10, 7, 5, 4, ...
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: you have to sort them as numbers not as strings.

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me how to sort them as numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store them as numbers (`NSNumber` objects) as that is the most appropriate type for this data.  During presentation you can convert them to strings:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayWithScores = ...;

// Insert new score
NSNumber score = @(10);
[arrayWithScores insertObject:score];

// Sort
[arrayWithScores sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    return [(NSNumber *)obj1 compare:(NSNumber *)obj2] == NSOrderedAscending;
}];
```

Comment: I prefer changing the type of the input params rather than casting the ids to objects... `...NSComparisonResult(NSNumber *number1, NSNumber *number2) {...` but this will do fine as is anyway :D

Comment: in the OP we don't know the type of the items, it would sound 'pervert', but the items can be strings. it would be better to compare the `doubleValue` instead, that is a valid method of both `NSNumber` and `NSString`.

Comment: @holex We do know the type of items; they are scores which are numbers so the best data type to represent them is `NSNumber` if they need to go into an Objective-C collection class.  The string is only needed during presentation and not for internal storage.

Comment: @trojanfoe, you can only _assume_ that those would be `NSNumbers`, but you don't have any evidence which makes you sure those are definitely `NSNumber` objects in the real OP's code. the OP's array can have even `@"10"` or `@(10)` objects, and the OP is about the objects are sorted as strings(!), inspite of the `NSNumber` has `–compare:` method would compare them as pure numbers. therefore no matter which type of object _would be_ logical to store numbers, it may not meet the OP's logic, therefore you cannot make such conclusion.

Comment: @holex I am pretty sure, given the outcome of his sort that the OP is using strings and my answer is actively encouraging him to use integers instead (wrapped in `NSNumber` objects so they can be stored in an Objective-C collection).  So I am not making assumptions; I am telling both *what* data type to use and *how* to use it.